# How do I get more presents?

Tags: ski-safari

One of the achievements in the holiday update for Ski Safari requires that you collect ten gifts. (They are located on clouds and when you bust through one of them you get 25 coins. Thanks, Santa!)

On a normal run (generally 700,000+ points) I'm lucky if I get 3 or 4 presents. What's the trick? How do I get more loots?

Answer (score 2):

I find riding the sleigh (with reindeer) is the best way, and just keep jumping each time you land - it keeps you at a good level to be able to collect the 'gifts'.

It only took me one or two goes using this method to reach the target.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The bat is the solution but first you should improve your flying skill with the bat, I got 12 presents in less than 500k score.
Why the bat? Because the bat is the only flying animal that can adjust the angle of flying to get every present in the way.
How doyou get it? We all know that you can't find a bat in the North Pole, so you will have to begin with the bat as the starting animal and that requires to get level 25 or 20 (I don't remember exactly the level). So good luck completing this challenge ;)